# AWS CodeDeploy Hook After Finishing Deployment to All Instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling, aws-code-deploy

I have AWS CodeDeploy deploying to a Deployment Group that targets an AutoScalingGroup of EC2 instances that can have between `min` and `max` number of instances.

[CodeDeploy hooks can be specified on **individual instances**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file-structure-hooks.html) to launch scripts on those instances at various stages of the deployment process.

Is there a way to launch a script, Lambda function, etc... after CodeDeploy successfully **finishes deploying to the final instance** in the ASG?  In other words, is there an "All Done With Everything" hook that I can use? How are others tackling and solving this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using codepipeline, how about adding another stage after code deploy?

Or you can also trigger SNS topic with AWS CodeDeploy about deployment status as well.

Here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/monitoring-cloudwatch-events.html